# Find the longest section of the negative numbers in the ArrayList

Tags: c#

I have this:

```
struct Weather {
    public int day;
    public int temperature;
    public Weather(int x, int y) {
        day = x;
        temperature = y;
    }
}
```

And i have an ArrayList which collects all this data created through the struct:

```
 ArrayList wthrList = new ArrayList();
```

Let we have 30 elements in the ArrayList. The "day" variable takes the values from 1 to 30. And the "temperature" variable takes the values from -30 to 30 (generated by the random). I need to find the longest section of the negative numbers. It means that if you have an array {0, -1, -2, 3, -3, -4, -5, 3}, then you will get the answer 3 (from index 4 to 6(-3, -4 and -5)). I already have this piece of the code, but now i'm stuck.

```
foreach (Weather w in wthrList) {
    if (w.temperature < 0) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I gotta say this:  `ArrayList` is way surpassed by its generic version `List<T>`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int negCount = 0;
int maxNegCount = 0;

foreach (Weather w in wthrList)
{
    negCount    = (w.temperature < 0) ? negCount + 1 : 0;
    maxNegCount = Math.max(negCount, maxNegCount);
}
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. Swap the lines in the else clause then it will work.

Comment: You will get wrong answer if the temperature values will be _{1, 1, 1, -1}_. negCount will be equal 1, but maxNegCount will be equal 0.